# ABAP CURSOR FETCH with multiple internal table

Tags: abap

I have a CURSOR below .

```
OPEN CURSOR WITH HOLD s_cursor FOR
  SELECT * FROM (QUERY_TABLE)   WHERE (OPTIONS).

DO.

    FETCH NEXT CURSOR s_cursor APPENDING TABLE <lt_itab>  PACKAGE SIZE 100000.
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      EXIT.
    ENDIF.
ENDDO.
```

Since I have huge data in the table , I need to split the data into multiple internal tables .
What want here is , need to pass different internal table for each `FECTH` .

Also I need to create multiple internal table with the same structure . 
Naming of internal table will be like below 
`CONCATENATE 'Lt_ITAB' count INTO intname` . 
I should be able to create the internal table from the variable intname .

Kindly provide some sample or logic .

Thanks in advance 
S Sukumar

Comment: 1) The principle of using a package size is to avoid keeping the whole data, because the memory is limited, so could you clarify the reason why you "need" to keep it? 2) I think that the question title doesn't reflect your question which is to "create the internal table dynamically" so that one is used at each FETCH, isn't it ? By the way did you think to use a "table of table" i.e. a 3 dimension-table?

Answer (score 2):

```
DATA tables TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF table_type WITH EMPTY KEY.

OPEN CURSOR WITH HOLD cursor FOR
  SELECT *
    FROM (db_table)
    WHERE (conditions).

WHILE sy-subrc = 0.
  INSERT NEW LINE INTO TABLE tables ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<target_table>).
  FETCH NEXT CURSOR cursor APPENDING TABLE <target_table> PACKAGE SIZE 100000.
ENDWHILE.
```

Note that **this doesn't make sense.** As Sandra Rossi points out, the idea of `FETCH CURSOR` is that the database stores much more data than ABAP's main memory can hold. You want to retrieve all of that data into main memory anyway - if your data set is really huge, you will run out of memory anyway.

If, on the other hand, your data set is small enough to fit into ABAP's main memory, you should instead load it in one go and apply a suitable packaging afterwards, as in

```
SELECT * FROM (db_table) INTO TABLE (all_data) WHERE (conditions).
DATA(tables) = split_data_in_packages( data = all_data  package_size = 100000 ).
```

Also note that **there is no way to create a set of `lt_itab<count>` variables dynamically.** My solution creates a table of tables instead, which can then be addressed conveniently with the `[]` index accessor as in `lt_itab[ <count> ]`.

This answer focuses on the packaging aspect. There is another aspect in your question, with `(db_table)` being dynamic and you probably not being aware of the actual table type until runtime. For these cases, you can refer to ABAP's Run-Time Type Interfaces (RTTI) and the `CREATE DATA` statement to determine and instantiate suitable data types.

Comment: There's one line in excess in `tables`, you should delete the last line after the last FETCH. By the way, Remark: it's possible to create `lt_itab<count>` via RTTC (as you say, but you limit it to the context of `(db_table)` being a dynamic database table), by using a table of references to tables and a field symbol to address the `nth` table.